# Javascript to change the size of qualtrics text box in [custom sum bar] questions

Tags: javascript, width, qualtrics

I need a Javascript to change the size of qualtrics text box in custom sum bars. Note it's a constant sum box not a normal question.

Make the "choice text" box WIDER and make the "bar box" shorter.

[Image showing what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqQoS.png)

I've tried all the codes I found on google to change qualtrics width but nothing worked. Need something simple, thank you!

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var inputWidth = "75px";
$(this.questionId).select('.SumInput').each(function(name, index) {
    name.style.width = inputWidth;
});
$(this.questionId).select('.SumTotal').each(function(name, index) {
    name.style.width = inputWidth;
}); 
$(this.questionId).select('.InputText').each(function(name, index) {
    name.style.width = inputWidth;
});
});
```

Also

```
function makeBigger(){ 
var txt = document.getelementbyid('txtbox');
txt.style['width'] = '100px';
}
```